# Dynamic form Builder in angular with formarray

Tags: angular, angular11

I had implemented the dynamic form builder in my project and it is working fine. But, now I need to add a form inside the dynamic form builder. Which will be like form inside a form. So, I had created a formarray inside my ts and it is coming correctly.

I am getting an error like

`ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '891713'`

This is what I had implemented
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Code sample I used is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder

So I had created a component named formControl inside the folder 'atoms' and if the control is fromControl, I am again calling field control.

**FormControl component**

```
            <td *ngFor="let itm of items; let i = index" formArrayName="childs" >
              <field-builder [field]="itm" [form]="form" ></field-builder>
            </td>
```

**FormControl component Ts**

```
  @Input() field: any = {};
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Output() sendDataToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  // form: FormGroup;
  itemLength: any;
  items: any;
  elemData = {}
  row = [];
  isDisabled : boolean = false;
  childs: FormArray;
  formNewStatus : boolean = true;
  // childs: any;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = this.field.items;
    this.itemLength = this.items.length
    this.items.forEach(element => {
      const elemId =element.id;
      this.elemData[elemId] = ''
    });
    console.log("from control form=====>",this.form)
    this.row.push(this.elemData);
  }

  addTable() {
    const frmArr = this.form.get('childs') as FormArray;
    this.sendDataToParent.emit("add");
    this.row.push(this.elemData)
    console.log("this.row===>",this.row)
  }
  
  deleteRow(x){
    this.row.splice(x, 1 );
  } 
  deleteAllRow(){
    console.log("came here")
    this.row = [];
  }
```

In the parent component, I had added the code for formarray to add more

```
  onFormControlValueChange(parentField:any){
    if(parentField === 'add'){
      this.childs = this.form.get('childs') as FormArray;
      this.childs.push(this.fb.group(this.createItem()));
    }
    console.log("this form====>", this.form)
  }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please share the appropriate TS code for both the form and the field-builder here on SO.

Comment: So you are recursive calling " field control." in the same component? Where is the logic for that and why you are doing that?

Comment: @WillAlexander I had Added the TS code also. All other codes are same in the stackblitz link I had mentioned

Comment: @VimalPatel That is actually my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puff, it's a large and complex improve the code to allow fromGroups and formArray, but we are going to try.

First we are going to change a few the DynamicFormBuilderComponent

We are going to create a function getForm to can make recursive create formGroup

```
  getForm(group: FormGroup, fields: any[]) {
    for (let f of fields) {
      switch (f.type) {
        case "group":
          group.addControl(f.name, new FormGroup({}));
          this.getForm(group.get(f.name) as FormGroup, f.children);

          break;
        case "checkbox":
          group.addControl(f.name, new FormGroup({}));
          const groupOption = group.get(f.name) as FormGroup;
          for (let opt of f.options) {
            groupOption.addControl(opt.key, new FormControl(opt.value));
          }
          break;
        case "array":
          group.addControl(f.name, new FormArray([]));
          const array = group.get(f.name) as FormArray;
          if (f.value)
          {
              f.value.forEach(x=>array.push(this.addGroupArray(f.children)))
              array.patchValue(f.value)
          }

        break;
        default:
          group.addControl(
            f.name,
            new FormControl(f.value || "", Validators.required)
          );
          break;
      }
    }
```

See that before we create an object `fields` and finally add the object fields to the formGroup. Using this function we directly create an empty formGroup and we are adding FormControls or FormGroup or a FormArray using `group.addControl`. This allow us call recursive the function if it's necesary.

So, in ngOnInit we make

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getForm(this.form, this.fields);
  }
```

See that we can access to the form from parent using a template variable

```
<dynamic-form-builder #dynamic ..>
{{dynamic.form?.value|json}}
```

And how I decide that the form has the "exact" model -before we has an object with {"fields:"exactModel"}-

And we need an auxiliar function to create the formGroup of a FormArray

```
  addGroupArray(fields:any[])
  {
     const group:FormGroup=new FormGroup({})
     fields.forEach(x=>{
       group.addControl(x.name,new FormControl(null,x.required?Validators.required:null))
     })
     return group
  }
```

Our FieldBuilderComponent sould take account the new two types of fields: "array" and "group". I go to put it inside a fieldset

```
  <!--in case group we repeat the field-builder using
     as form the "getFormGroup" and as field "field.children"
  -->
  <fieldset *ngSwitchCase="'group'">
     <legend>{{field.name}}</legend>
     <field-builder *ngFor="let item of field.children"
       [form]="getFormGroup(field.name)" [field]="item">
     </field-builder>
  </fieldset>

  <!--in case array we create a table and use the function
      "getFormArray"
  -->

  <fieldset *ngSwitchCase="'array'">
     <legend>{{field.name}}</legend>
      <table [formArrayName]="field.name">
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let item of field.children">{{item.label}}</th>
          <th>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getFormArray(field.name).push(this.addGroupArray(field.children))">Add</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let group of getFormArray(field.name).controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
           <td *ngFor="let item of field.children">
              <field-builder noLabel="true" [form]="getFormArray(field.name).at(i)"
                [field]="item">
              </field-builder>
            </td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getFormArray(field.name).removeAt(i)">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
```

I use two auxiliar function that only return "casted" the formGroup and the formArray

```
  getFormGroup(field:string)
  {
    return this.form.get(field) as FormGroup
  }
  getFormArray(field:string)
  {
    return this.form.get(field) as FormArray
  }
```

See how inside we call to the own component. I need add an "attribute" noLabel to not show the label in case we are mannage a FormArrayLabel

```
  //in constructor
  constructor(@Attribute('noLabel') noLabel) { 
    this.noLabel=noLabel || false;
  }
```

And use

```
 <label *ngIf="!noLabel" ....></label>
```

I need to repeat the function `addGroupArray` again in this component (I can't imagine another way)

Well, the only to take account is how dive value to the formArray, see that the field of an array is like:

```
{
  type: "array",
  name: "arrayName",
  value:[{firstName:"array",lastName:"array lastName"}],
  children: [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "firstName",
      label: "First Name",
      required: true
    },
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "lastName",
      label: "Last Name",
      required: true
    }
  ]
},
```

As usually this is [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-builder-nvbskl?file=app%2Fdynamic-form-builder%2Fdynamic-form-builder.component.ts) without warranty

NOTE: the atom for options should be

```
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let opt of field.options">
      <label class="form-check-label">
      <input [formControlName]="field.name"  class="form-check-input" type="radio" [value]="opt.key" >
        {{opt.label}}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Update** Really I never like "split" a series of checkbox in an array with true/false values. It's more natural that the value was, e.g. "c,f" and is checked the check box "cooking" and "fishing".

Well, the first is change the "atom checkbox" using `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`. First we are going to create two auxiliar functions:

```
  //a simple "getter" to get the value
  get value() {
    return this.form ? this.form.get(this.field.name).value : null;
  }

  //we pass "checked" and the "key" of the option
  change(checked: boolean, key: any) {
    const oldvalue = this.form.get(this.field.name).value || null;

     //if has no value
    if (!oldvalue) {
      //use setValue with the "key" (if checked) or null
      this.form.get(this.field.name).setValue(checked ? "" + key : null);
      return;
    } else {

      //in value store all the options that fullfilled with the condition
      const value = checked
        ? this.field.options.filter( //is in the old value or is the key

            x => oldvalue.indexOf(x.key) >= 0 || x.key == key
          )
        : this.field.options.filter(  //is in the old value and is not the key
            x => oldvalue.indexOf(x.key) >= 0 && x.key != key
          );

      //we give the value null if there're no options that fullfilled
      //or a join of the keys
      this.form
        .get(this.field.name)
        .setValue(value.length > 0 ? value.map(x => x.key).join(",") : null);
    }
  }
```

Well, now we can use our [ngModel] and (ngModelChange). We need say to Angular that is a "standalone"

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngFor="let opt of field.options" class="form-check form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input
            [ngModel]="value && value.indexOf(opt.key) >= 0"
            (ngModelChange)="change($event, opt.key)"
            [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            id="inlineCheckbox1"
            value="option1"
          />
          {{ opt.label }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So, we remove the case of "checkbox" in out function getForm

```
  getForm(group: FormGroup, fields: any[]) {
    for (let f of fields) {
      switch (f.type) {
        case "group":
          ...
          break;
        case "array":
           ....
        break;
        default:
          ...
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Eliseo . I could Fix my issue by looking into the way you gave here