# How to get element from HTML (Angular)

Tags: angular, forms, dom

I have a little problem, I want to create a form using Angular :
here is my HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="requeteForm" (ngSubmit)="ajouter()" *ngIf=" tables!= null">
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let col of colonne; let i=index">
            <label for="{{col}}">{{col}}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{col}}" formControlName="{{col}}">
        </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the formControlName take a variable, the problem is how can I get the variable to init the formGroup ?
For exemple :

```
this.requeteForm = this.formBuilder.group(
            {
              {{col}}: ['', Validators.required], //It's just an exemple about what I want to do
              
            }
        );
```

**UPDATE**

I want to bring in some more information :
I fact what I want to do is to create a form to add parameters in my dataBase the thing is I get all the columns's name in an Array so I have colonne[nom, number] that are the name of my colums.

The problem is that they don't have a "title" like {id : 1, name : 'Tom'} so I the formBuilder I can't use nom and number since it will change is the table change... I have tried using a for in this.colonne but the syntaxe is wrong for the formBuilder TT Another problem is how to get the information of the input since I won't be able to call them using particular name...

Hope you can help me ^^ Thank you

Comment: Don't I need to have a different one for each col ? So that I can get later using : 
`const formValue = this.requeteForm.value;
    let element = {
      selectCol: formValue.selectCol,
    }`

Comment: In fact I have an array named colonne which contain : (nom, nombre) I want to input for nom and nombre, but colonne depend on what I have in my dataBase that's why I need to use variable

Comment: yeah, it's defined, sorry, my bad, you need to use formArray

Comment: No problem, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `FormArray` which contains `FormControl`.
Try like this :

```
requestForm: FormGroup;

colonne = [
  { id: 1, name: "Name 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "Name 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Name 3" },
  { id: 4, name: "Name 4" },
];

get cols() {
  return this.requestForm.get("cols") as FormArray;
}

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.requestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    cols: new FormArray(this.colonne.map(col => new FormGroup({
      item: new FormControl(col.name)
    })))
  });
}

ajouter() {

}
```

Then in your HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="requestForm" (ngSubmit)="ajouter()">

  <ng-container formArrayName="cols">
    <div *ngFor="let col of cols.controls; index as i">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="item" />
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

This code is not tested so maybe you will have to adjust. You have a whole example here : https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

**UPDATE**

I've made a working StackBlitz (without `ajouter()` function) here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wympwa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you ^^ If I have understand the get cols create an array with everything in the form is that right ?

Comment: @snsdtiti I've updated my code and give you a working example. Please check and tell me if it's working. The `get` allow you to access your FormArray. You need it to display each item into the HTML.

Comment: It's working better, I now have the input with the name inside ^^ But i have some errors I don't really know how to repair : Cannot read property 'get' of undefined for the line `return this.requeteForm.get('cols') as FormArray;`  
And how can I get the result of the input ?

Comment: And I forgot but I have also this error : `formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in` But your code seem right...

Comment: Be careful to the imports. Make sure you imported `FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule` in you `.module.ts`. For the first error, add a `?` like this `this.requestForm?.get('...') as FormArray`

Comment: Thank you ! I got the error ^^ It seem like it's working know I still have a question about how to get the result of the values I will input 
If you want my code it's here :  stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hawae7

Comment: I don't understand your Stackblitz. You should Mock your service and use fake datas.
All the informations about your form can be retrieve with `console.log(this.form.get('cols').value)`, or `console.log(this.cols)`. If my answer help you, please upvote. If it solved your issue, please mark it as resolved. Otherwise, post your own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FormArray or a FormGroup. You choice one or another according the data you need.

```
//If you create a FormGroup is because you need a data like
{
   name1:"Peter"
   surname:"Smith"
}
//If you create a FormArray of FormControls is because you need a data like
[
   "Peter","John"
]
//If you create a FormArray of FormGroup is because you need a data like
[
   {name:"Peter",surname:"Smith"},
   {name:"John",surname:"Jhon"}
]
```

If we want create a FormGroup according an array of columns you need create a FormGroup empty and use addControl, e.g.

```
const columns=["name","surname"]
const form=new FormGroup({})  //create an empty formGroup
columns.forEach(x=>{
   form.addControl(x,new FormControl()) //add a FormControl to the formGroup
})
```

Note:recently @Raru ask about a dynamic form builder in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67103172/dynamic-form-builder-in-angular-with-formarray)